# Getting SharePoint document library location using C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint, document

So I'm trying to get the location of a document library, but I've become stuck on how to proceed. This is what I've got so far:

```
    public string GetLibraryLocation()
    {
        var location = "";
        SPSite siteCollection = SPContext.Current.Site;
        var siteString = siteCollection.ToString();
        //SPWebCollection collectionWebsites = siteCollection.AllWebs;

        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteString))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPListCollection docLibCollection = web.GetListsOfType(SPBaseType.DocumentLibrary);

                // Where to go from here..

            }
        }

        return location;
    }
```

What I'm trying to achieve is writing a method that can give me the location of the document library in the shape of an URL. With that URL, the plan is to obtain a folder residing in the library, which I'm then going to insert a file into. But I'm currently stuck on just obtaining the library URL. Any hints appreciated!

Comment: Do you have name of Library?

Comment: The library's name is simply: `DocumentLibrary`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add file in Library try like following

```
 SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate(){

            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(""))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    SPList Library = web.Lists.TryGetList("Document Lib");
                    Library.RootFolder.Files.Add("Nameoffile",bytearray);

                }
            }

        });
```

if you want URL of Library

string url= web.ServerRelativeUrl+"\LibraryName";